# How to copy from a textbox to a <select>

Tags: javascript

I want to copy the value inserted in a textbox to a select control, onclick of a button using javascript. I want to insert multiple values to get multiple options in the select.`

```
    var temp1 = document.getElementById("textboxID").value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    setSelectValue('selectID', temp1);

function setSelectValue (id, val) {
document.getElementById(id).value = val;}
```

This is my code and is not working. Thank you
  `

Comment: what do you mean by a 'select control'?

Comment: Check HTML select tag. I want to add options to it programatically.

Comment: @ jpgrassi:  prefer not to, Still  if you know the code for jQuery i will be thankful to see it.

Comment: What exactly is "*not working*"? Are there any errors of any kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example (https://jsbin.com/sekihofihu/edit?html,output):

```
<input id="textboxID" />
<button onclick="addOption()">Copy</button>
<select id="selectID"></select>
<script>
var addOption = function()
{
  var val = document.getElementById("textboxID").value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  var select = document.getElementById('selectID');
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = val;
  select.add(option);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the content of the text input to your select as a new option you can use this:

```
    var temp1 = document.getElementById("textboxID").value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    setSelectValue('selectID', temp1);


function setSelectValue (id, val) {
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<option value='" + val + "' >" + val + "</option>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not super clear but if you're trying to add an "option" element into a select element you can do something like this:

```
  <html>
      <body>
        <select id="targetSelect" ></select>    
        <input id="sourceInput" type="Text" > </input>
        <button id="submit" type="button" onclick="setSelectValue()"> 
          Add to Select
       </button>
       <script>
        function setSelectValue () {
             var mySelectElement = document.getElementById("targetSelect");     
             var newOption = document.createElement("option");
             newOption.text = document.getElementById("sourceInput").value;
             mySelectElement.add(newOption,0);        
        }
      </script>    
   </body>
 </html>
```